# neo4j - no procedure CALL dbms.security.listRoles()

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I installed a neo4j db on linux and windows, but i am facing the following issue. I can add users etc., but when i want to add roles to users it seems not be defined :( For example if i call the cyhper query:

CALL dbms.security.listRoles()

neo4j answer:
There is no procedure with the name `dbms.security.listRoles` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Is it not implemented in the community version? Or do i have to enable roles or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roles and User management are available in Neo4j Enterprise.

But if you are a private user or a startup or so you would be eligible for a free enterprise version: https://neo4j.com/licensing/